# I need a method to over-ride a 3d secure referrer in google analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics, analytics

I have a new google analytics installation on an ecommerce website. Currently, a visit gets assigned a referrer when they enter the site, and then that referrer is over-written when the user goes through checkout and is directed to an offsite 3d-secure page.

Now, when the user comes back and their purchase is registered by Google Analytics, the purchase is recorded against a referrer of the 3d secure page they've just come from, not the original referrer that brought them to the site.

I need to over-ride that second referrer. The only approach I can think of is to use a regex filter to check if the referrer field contains one of a number of sites, and if so to set the field to blank.

Unfortunately, I don't know if setting a field to blank using an advanced filter sets the field to be a blank string, but still over-ride the previous value, or if it doesn't set the value at all, and so preserves the previous value. I don't want to make the change on a live site, so I'm asking here if anyone knows what the likely result would be.

Here's a quick diagram of the problem:

```
| Pageview 1 - arrives at site (Initial referrer is set)
|
| Pageviews 2 through 5 - browses around
|
| Pageview 6 - enters checkout
|
| Pageview 7 - Sent off-site to 3d secure by checkout
|
| Pageview 8 - Returned to site from 3d secure website (Referrer is over-written to 3d secure website)
|
| Pageview 9 - Purchase is completed revenue assigend to most recent referrer (3d secure page)
```

I want to know if using an advanced filter to set the referrer on pageview 8 to "", will cause the revenue to be assigned to the initial referrer, or if it will be assigned to a new pageview 8 referrer of "".

I am aware that I could solve this problem by setting utm_nooverride=1 in the query string of the link that the external site uses to link back to my ecommerce site. However, for business reasons that isn't possible in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is just to signal to Google Analytics ignore that referrer. In that case the previous traffic source wil be reused.

If you are using the async snippet you should use the method [_addIgnoredRef()](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiSearchEngines#_gat.GA_Tracker_._addIgnoredRef).

Add the following calls after the `_setAccount` call.

```
_gaq.push(['_addIgnoredRef', 'checkoutsiteA.com']);
_gaq.push(['_addIgnoredRef', 'checkoutsiteB.com']);
_gaq.push(['_addIgnoredRef', 'checkoutsiteC.com']);
```

If you have several checkout sites you can ignore several of them.

If you are using Universal analytics [Ignored Referrals must be set on the Admin interface](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en).

No filters are necessary.